# how to my receiver is typing a message and show on my browser

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

i want to check the user is typing a message and want to display it in my chat box, i know setting database flag and checking it by timeinterval function, but i think it should be slow method, is there any way to check it? by the users's machine ip/id .

Comment: use websocket it will be way more efficient.

Comment: how to use that? can u suggest me any better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using sockets is the only good solution for achieving that. https://wisembly.github.io/elephant.io/ .

PHP server side:

```
use ElephantIO\Client as Elephant;

$elephant = new Elephant('http://localhost:8000', 'socket.io', 1, false, true, true);

$elephant->init();
$elephant->send(
    ElephantIOClient::TYPE_EVENT,
    null,
    null,
    json_encode(array('name' => 'foo', 'args' => 'bar'))
);
$elephant->close();

echo 'tryin to send `bar` to the event `foo`';
```

Socket.io server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('user connected!');

   socket.on('foo', function (data) {
     console.log('here we are in action event and data is: ' + data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Use `Websocket` for this

use this link this will help you
https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Answer (score 2):

You can implement web sockets on your server, so you can pass events between your clients and server.

you can check Ratchet: http://socketo.me/ for php or Socket.io for Nodejs.

Than you can bind on "keyup" an event to notify server of typing, i suggest to throttle the events so you wont end with too many request :)

Comment: Yes, of course if you must to. since you only want to show when user is typing you can receive this typing event on the server and broadcast it back to online users, without the need to store in the db. But if you want to, you cant of course store it in the DB and retrieve it later.

Comment: you can also use websocket for your entire chat app , so you want have to refresh the data on the client on every message sent, just publish socket event from server of new message.

Answer (score 1):

i think socket.io is what you looking for  http://socket.io/get-started/chat/